# Cast iPad screen to Windows PC with cable

Tags: ipad, quicktime

I like the feature on MacBooks that allows me to plug in my iPad and get a mirror of the screen using QuickTime so that I can project it using the MacBook.

Work machine is a PC and I would like to do this with it.

Is there any way to mirror an iPad (9th gen, non-pro) screen to PC (with a USB cable) without strange 3rd-party software?

Is there a version of QuickTime for Windows that supports this?

Comment: Seems like a pc problem.

Comment: I'd think this would be a 3rd party solution. Quicktime for Windows was abandoned 5 or 6 years ago.